# Activator.updated() method is not called in osgi

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, activator

I am using Apache Felix for osgi. Other bundles are running just fine. I've add new bundle to the reactor. The Activator.init() method is called. But I will never get into the updated() method. Any ideas?

```
public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase implements ManagedServiceFactory {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Activator.class);

    public static final String PID = "my.unique.pid";
    private final Map<String, Component> components = new HashMap<>();
    private volatile DependencyManager dependencyManager; /* injected by dependency manager */


    @Override
    public void init(BundleContext bc, DependencyManager dm) throws Exception {     
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Constants.SERVICE_PID, PID);
        dm.add(createComponent()
                .setInterface(ManagedServiceFactory.class.getName(), props)
                .setImplementation(this)
                .add(createConfigurationDependency().setPid(PID))
                );

        dm.add(createComponent()
                .setInterface(SessionRegister.class.getName(), null)
                .setImplementation(SessionRegisterImpl.class)
                );

        dm.add(createComponent()
                .setInterface(Plugin.class.getName(), null)
                .setImplementation(PriorityActionHandler.class)
                .add(createServiceDependency().setRequired(true).setService(PluginManager.class))
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void updated(String pid, Dictionary<String, ?> properties) throws ConfigurationException {
        logger.debug("This method should be called and run!");


        if (properties == null) {
            logger.warn("Configuration is empty!");
            return;
        }

.
.
.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `init` method is likely not what you intended. You create a component that is a `ManagedServiceFactory`, with a `PID`, and you also make that same component have a service dependency (which translates to making it a `ManagedService`, with the same `PID`, which is not allowed and definitely confusing). I am assuming you meant either of these two.

The updated method you have right now assumes you wanted to be a `ManagedServiceFactory` and there updated will be invoked for each configuration (one or more) that you provide. From your code I cannot see if you have an implementation of Configuration Admin installed and if you actually somehow provide one or more configurations for this `PID`.

Please provide more information to further pinpoint this issue if this answer does not help you yet.

Comment: nevermind...the problem was in init() method... this ".add(createConfigurationDependency().setPid(PID))" should not be there...it should be in the updated() method.

Comment: I don't quite follow your reasoning there. Why whould the updated() method need to add a configuration dependency (when the component is already a ManagedServiceFactory)?